# Put Last Two Digits Behind Decimal

Tags: decimal

I have a column in SQL that uses an integer data type.  What is the best way to get the values from the column where the last two digits of the integer are a decimal.  These results would need to be displayed in a new column.

Example:

COL_1     Col_2

25489 -> 254.89

489196 -> 4891.96

250 -> 2.50

77 -> .77

Comment: Heh...  Either one of the two answers are correct.  Math for the win!

Answer (score 0):

It's easier than you think.  Simply cast the value as a float and multiply it by 0.01.  that will create a new value with the decimal two over from the right.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to divide it by 100:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET    col2 = col1 / 100.0
```